# TextView как убрать отступ справа?

Tags: java, android

Как убрать отмеченный красным отступ в TextView? При этом надо оставить android:gravity="left" у TextView.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Uac.png]

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline7">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tw_word"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:shadowColor="#E9E2BF"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:text="abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmno pqrstuvwxyz"
                android:textColor="#E9E2BF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Это не отступ, у вас слова не помещаются в строчку и поэтому происходит перенос на новую строку (перенос по пробелу). Можете убрать пробелы в своем тексте и увидите что отступа нету.

Comment: @АнтонХ ок, слова переносятся на новую строчку, но мне не нужно то пространство (отмеченное красным), которое они оставляют. Как его убрать? Пробелы между словами мне нужны.

Comment: вы хотите убрать пустое пространство для каких-то нужд, или просто потому что так хочется?

Comment: Как понять "как его убрать"? На экране все равно будет то пустое место.

Comment: @АнтонХ хочу его убрать, чтобы текст в TextView был по горизонтальному центру экрана. Сейчас видно, что текст смещен влево относительно центра. При этом я хочу, чтобы каждая линия начиналась с одного и того же места как при использовании android:gravity="left". По этому android:gravity="center_horizontal" не подходит.

Comment: Вы хотите очень странное поведение. Я могу предложить вам вот такой вариант:   

   '<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="tsdtds fdsdsfsdsfdsfdsfds \nтdasfdsfdfdsdsfsdsfsdfdfdajfnjgjfnasdfdfd "
            android:textAlignment="textStart" />'

Comment: @АнтонХ К сожалению, с моим текстом это не дает никакого эффекта.

Comment: Я специально дал вам свой текст чтоб вы поигрались с ним и сделали выводы)  Представьте что вы добавляете в TextView по одному символу и его ширина соответсвенно увеличивается, и в конце она становится равной ширине экрана (как и ваша вью). Потом когда вы добавляете новый символ то он не помещается на экран и должен быть перенесен на новую строку (вроде логично). В вашей ситуации вы имеете два длинных слова и они не помещаются в ширину экрана (строку) , соотвественно происходит перенос, но перенос не просто тех символов которые не поместились, а именно слов.

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tw_word"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:shadowColor="#E9E2BF"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                android:text="abcdefghij\n klmnopqrstuvwxyz\n abcdefghijklmno\n pqrstuvwxyz"
                android:textColor="#E9E2BF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```